# How to use the statistics object to find the mean confidence interval in Anylogic?

Tags: statistics, anylogic, confidence-interval

Assuming that my confidence level is 95%, how do I use the statistics object to calculate the mean confidence level? What kind of data do I need?
There is an API in continuous stats called double meanConfidence(), but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a data point by calling `myStatsObject.add(x)` where x is a number.

Then, you can access the statistics of all the data points added by calling `myStatsObjects.meanConfidence()` or all those other API functions it has.

Check lots of example models to learn more about how to use objects, access their functions, etc. :)